# Blender v3.6 Geometry nodes viewport & rendering not displaying

Tags: node-editor, 3d-view

Something strange happened to my node group overnight. I viewed the node group output in the viewport, and everything looked as it was suppose to, I left computer and when I returned in the morning the node group would not display at all in viewport, I rendered the image I only got bit and pieces and jumbled. Maybe the cat danced on the keyboard while I was away, but I think it is something else. I added a mesh cube directly to the group output and this would not display either. I am at wits end on how to get this back to display correctly. Probably something simple to fix but after using blender for a few years now I have never come across this before.
I would attach file but it's too big 271MB (even though I think I've deleted everything but mesh cube-which maybe a clue).

Comment: if you want to share the file and it's too big for stackexchange then you could upload it to google drive, drive one, dropbox or another file share hoster and share the link to access the file.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aps3j2WLXHIFmGTIwDxm-NfqT9Cp?e=JBrdgE

Comment: shared files onedrive previous post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you just have to click on that screen icon: display modifier in viewport

Comment: God, sometimes I hate Blender, so many buttons and options. But that also the great part as well.